# libimobiledevice work on ubuntu but not in raspberry

Tags: compiling

I recently installed libimobiledevice in ubuntu via `sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice` and it worked like a charm with ios 8.1.2 ...

But when I compile and install the latest libimobiledevice in raspberry.`ideviceinfo` or `ideviceinstaller` always give me the following error

```
ERROR: Could not connect to lockdownd, error code -16
```

If this is a bug in the latest version, how can I know what is the version installed in Ubuntu so that I can download that version and compile on a raspberry pi ?

This is the latest install script `libimobiledevice` that I used for install :

```
git clone https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libplist.git
git clone https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libusbmuxd.git
git clone https://github.com/libimobiledevice/usbmuxd.git
git clone https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice.git
git clone https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse.git

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
echo "export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig" | sudo tee -a /etc/bash.bashrc

cd libplist && ./autogen.sh && make && sudo make install && cd ..
cd libusbmuxd && ./autogen.sh && make && sudo make install && cd ..
cd libimobiledevice && ./autogen.sh && make && sudo make install && cd ..
cd usbmuxd && ./autogen.sh && make && sudo make install && cd ..
cd ifuse && ./autogen.sh && make && sudo make install && cd ..

groupadd -g 140 usbmux &>/dev/null
useradd -c 'usbmux user' -u 140 -g usbmux -d / -s /sbin/nologin usbmux &>/dev/null
passwd -l usbmux &>/dev/null

echo /usr/local/lib | sudo tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libimobiledevice-libs.conf
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: the debian package has armel versions, ubuntu only has i386 and amd64 https://packages.debian.org/search?arch=armel&searchon=names&keywords=libimobiledevice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show information about a package, including its version, open the terminal and type:

```
apt-cache show package-name
```

Replace package-name in the above command with the name of your package. The problem is there is no package called *libimobiledevice* in the Ubuntu repositories, but there are a few packages with names that are similar to *libimobiledevice* (e.g. libimobiledevice4). To show these packages run the following command:

```
apt-cache search libimobiledevice*
```